# How to connect to mysql database with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Jetbrains and Mysql to work on this practical project, but when I connect to the mysql
database it gives me the following error:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.40\php.exe C:\wamp64\www\Social_Network\Includes\connection.php
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'social_network'
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I made sure several times that the database name is the same name and there are
no spelling errors at all (I copy pasted it from the database)

Here's my code:

```
  <?php


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=social_network", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


//?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welll, there's little that can be done about it. **MySQL thinks that the database does not exist**.

- is the server the correct one?
- is the case sensitivity set correctly? "Social_Network" and "social_network" might be considered different.
- can you access the database with those parameters using a different tool (e.g. HeidiSQL, SQLYog, SQLterm, in a pinch even phpMyAdmin)?

Actually, JetBrains PHPStorm has a SQL terminal utility that can diagnose the connection. You may want to use it (once it knows what database you're connecting to, it will also warn you of several possible errors such as using the wrong table name or column name).